# Creating a frequency polygon overlay in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a frequency polygon overlay plot in R. I have been able to generate relative frequency tables for responses to a 3-question survey, with responses given as discrete values for 1-5.

How can I make a frequency polygon plot that represents the information below (the percent of respondents per event) for multiple events on the same plot?

Here's the dput for the table:

```
dput(t1)
structure(c(1.33196721311475, 0.867678958785249, 0.995024875621891, 
0.544069640914037, 1.0498687664042, 0, 0.759219088937093, 0.66334991708126, 
0.217627856365615, 0, 1.63934426229508, 6.83297180043384, 0.995024875621891, 
0.870511425462459, 1.0498687664042, 19.5696721311475, 37.0932754880694, 
26.6998341625207, 20.2393906420022, 20.4724409448819, 77.4590163934426, 
54.4468546637744, 70.6467661691542, 78.1284004352557, 77.4278215223097
), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")), .Names = c("", "")))
```

I am also trying to color code the events, so they are differentiated on the resultant plot.

[image: January Events Relative Frequency Table]

This is what the desired frequency polygon plot would look like (in Excel), however Excel is super inefficient for a task like this, so I thought R could do a better job!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward using a little data wrangling and ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

 pivot_longer(as.data.frame(cbind(t(t1), n = 1:5)), 1:5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, value, colour = name)) +
   geom_line() +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>